# ActionBarSherlock - refreshing tab on updating from another tab

Tags: android, tabs, refresh, actionbarsherlock, swipe

In my application, I use the library **ActionBarSherlock**, and i have 3 tabs and use the swiping gesture (catch in the sample).

Example :

- I go the tab n°2, and change some parameters.
- If I go immediately to the tab n°3, the view of this tab was not reloaded.
- I need to go to the n°1 and after navigate to the n°3 for refresh them.

I need to find how to refresh my tab n°3 if I update something on the n°2.